# Можно ли вывести данные из таблицы в БД(SQL Server) в консоль в c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Есть вопрос можно ли в консоль вывести данные из таблицы ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace pr9_10
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=HOME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cinema;Integrated Security=True;";
            Console.Write("Парамеры командной строки: ");
            Console.WriteLine(connectionString);


            string query1 = "SELECT * FROM Movies";


            SqlConnection sqlCnct = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlCnct.Open();
            if (sqlCnct.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Подключение установлено!");
            }

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query1, sqlCnct);
        }

    }
}
```

Я вот в `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query1, sqlCnct);` передал запрос на выборку, но как его вывести?

Comment: Я так понимаю, вопрос не в выводе в консоль, а собственно в получении ответа от SQL-сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=HOME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cinema;Integrated Security=True;";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Movies";

    using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int id = reader.GetIn32(0);
        string name = reader.GetString(1);
        Console.WriteLine($"{id} {name}");
    }
}
```

Убрал лишнее, чтобы сократить код в ответе.

Comment: У меня ошибка здесь ```string text = reader.GetString(0);``` **Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Int32" к типу "System.String".**
я сделал ```int value = reader.GetInt32(0);
Console.WriteLine(value);
``` 
Но у меня выводятся только цифры

Comment: @Lcfr значит у вас цифры в первой колонке таблицы, верно? `0` - первая колонка, `1` - вторая и так далее.

Comment: У меня в первом столбце id от 1 до 3, далее во второй имя, описание, длительность, рейтинг, бюджет.
Вот как это вывести ?

Comment: @Lcfr обновил ответ, дальше догадаетесь?

Comment: Понял спасибо! А если в таблице много столбцов для каждой прописывать переменные ? Т.е для обычного просмотра таблицы нужно переменные создавать ?

Comment: @Lcfr ну поля в таблице же просто так не появляются, а как правило в результате миграций, а миграции в результате доработки кода. Таблицы можно и динамически просматривать, но как обычно в этом смысла никакого.

Comment: Поставил галочку) Можно последний вопрос, using обязательно использовать ?

Comment: @Lcfr [есть правила](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) работы с `IDisposable` объектами. Из них очень мало исключений. Поэтому да, обязательно.